# Time limit exceeded in valid parentheses problem

Tags: python, parentheses

I am trying to solve the following problem in python (not for anything, just trying to learn how to code), and I keep getting the time limit exceeded error.

> Given a string s containing just the characters '(', ')', '{', '}', '[' and ']', determine if the input string is valid.
>
> An input string is valid if:
>
> - Open brackets must be closed by the same type of brackets.
> - Open brackets must be closed in the correct order.

Can someone please explain why the code won't run?

Detail on my logic: I am trying to check if the input has any values (or else return true immediately), then whether it has any closed parentheses next to each other. The idea is that every true input must have either '()', '[]', or '{}' somewhere in the string. Then, I would remove those pairs until either there are no more characters, and I know it's true, or it can't find any and it is false.

If this is a poor way to think about the problem and you plan to offer a different way, please also help me understand why this code doesn't run.

```
class Solution:
    def isValid(self, s: str) -> bool:
        l = ['()','[]','{}']
        while s != '':
            while l[0] in s or l[1] in s or l[2] in s:
                try:
                    s.replace(s[s.index(l[0])],'')
                except:
                    ValueError
                try:
                    s.replace(s[s.index(l[1])],'')
                except:
                    ValueError
                try:
                    s.replace(s[s.index(l[2])],'')
                except:
                    ValueError
                continue
            return False
        return True
```

Comment: You are scanning the string about 97 times on each iteration. You can solve this by processing each character in the string exactly once. And your code doesn't actually solve the problem in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`s.replace(...)` returns the modified string. It doesn't modify `s` in place; it can't, since strings are immutable.

There are other mistakes but I'll leave them as an exercise for you to figure out. Fixing this will at least get you past the infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks so much for the insight! I also appreciate the exercise.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to the above answers, it seems like you are trying to catch a ValueError when s.index() fails.

The code you have will instead catch any exception, not just ValueError.

You can do it like this:

```
try:
    # try code
except ValueError as e:
    # handle ValueError
```